# Não atualizar um determinado campo EF asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Eu tenho uma tabela que toda vez que eu crio um novo cadastro tem o campo Datacadastro, porem quando eu quero editar eu não quero mudar a data que foi cadastrada e só altera os outros campos.Eu já tentei fazer de um jeito que pela lógica funciona mas quando vai aplicar no banco da erro.

```
        [Key]
    public int ConsertoId { get; set; }


    public string Defeito { get; set; }

    public string Solucao { get; set; }


    public int MecanicoId { get; set; }

    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("MecanicoId")]
    public virtual Usuario Pessoa { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
    public virtual Usuario Cliente { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Clientes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Mecanicos { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ConsertoDetalhes> ConsertoDetalhes { get; set; }
```

controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Editar(Consertos conserto)
    {
        Db db = new Db();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             //pega data ja cadastrada mas da erro
            // Consertos cons = db.Conserto.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConsertoId == conserto.ConsertoId);
           // conserto.DataCriacao = cons.DataCriacao; 

            conserto.DataCriacao = DateTime.Now;//funciona mas cria nova data
            db.Entry(conserto).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            TempData["MG"] = "Tarefa atualziada com sucesso";
            return RedirectToAction("Editar");

        }
        ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(db.Usuario.Where(u => u.Cliente).OrderBy(u => u.Nome), "UserId", "Nome", conserto.ConsertoId);
        ViewBag.MecanicoId = new SelectList(db.Usuario.Where(u => u.Mecanico).OrderBy(u => u.Nome), "UserId", "Nome", conserto.ConsertoId);
        //conserto.Clientes = new SelectList(db.Usuario.Where(u => u.Cliente).OrderBy(u => u.Nome), "UserId", "Nome", conserto.ConsertoId);

        return View(conserto);


    }
```

Erro:Attaching an entity of type 'Conserto.Models.Consertos' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

se eu deixar sem nada recebo erro:
A conversão de um tipo de dados datetime2 em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo.
A instrução foi finalizada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após setar que o objeto foi modificado com o `EntityState.Modified` você pode indicar as propriedades que não quer modificar com o `IsModified = false`, seu método ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Editar(Consertos conserto)
    {
        Db db = new Db();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            conserto.DataCriacao = DateTime.Now;//funciona mas cria nova data
            db.Entry(conserto).State = EntityState.Modified;

            //Indica qual propriedade não deve ser alterada
            db.Entry(conserto).Property(p => p.Datacadastro).IsModified = false;
            db.SaveChanges();

            TempData["MG"] = "Tarefa atualziada com sucesso";
            return RedirectToAction("Editar");

        }
        ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(db.Usuario.Where(u => u.Cliente).OrderBy(u => u.Nome), "UserId", "Nome", conserto.ConsertoId);
        ViewBag.MecanicoId = new SelectList(db.Usuario.Where(u => u.Mecanico).OrderBy(u => u.Nome), "UserId", "Nome", conserto.ConsertoId);

        return View(conserto);
    }
```

Comment: Funcionou erá só usar essa linha que voce disse mesmo. Obrigado. eu tava ficando maluco já haha.

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Eu sei que já fazem mais de dois anos desde a pergunta e já foi até mesmo respondida corretamente, mas apenas para esclarecer caso alguma outra pessoa caia aqui de paraquedas, o seu erro ocorreu porque no seu método haviam duas entidades rastreadas do mesmo tipo (Consertos).

Caso você adicionasse a propriedade `AsNoTracking()` à sua consulta, seria possível fazer a atribuição manual da forma que tentou.

Como o próprio nome diz, essa propriedade desabilita o tracking/rastreio da entidade em questão, fazendo com que ela se torne uma entidade apenas de visualização.

A forma completa da consulta ficaria:

```
Consertos cons = db.Conserto.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConsertoId == conserto.ConsertoId);
```